# How do I remove the glitched text after updating a Tkinter label?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a Tkinter app that changes the text of a label after doing certain things, and whenever I change the text value of the label and then re-grid it, the old text is still there behind it. I tried `label.grid_forget()` but that didn't fix it. Here's something like what I have so far:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
# Update text function
def update(txt):
  global label
  label = Label(root, text=txt)
  label.grid(row = 1, columnspan = 2, padx=5, pady=5)
# Button 1
btn1 = Button(root, text="Button #1", command=lambda:update("You clicked button #1! My favorite."))
btn1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx=5, pady=5)
# Button 2
btn2 = Button(root, text="Button #2", command=lambda:update("You clicked button #2."))
btn2.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx=5, pady=5)
# Label
label = Label(root, text="Click the buttons to change me.")
label.grid(row = 1, columnspan = 2, padx=5, pady=5)
```

The code brings up two buttons and a text label that attempts to do as I described. After clicking both buttons, one of them is still visible from behind and I do not know to fix this. Any help would be appretiated.

Comment: your `def update(txt):` should only contain `label.config(text=txt)`

Comment: Oh, thank you! I didn't know I could that. Next time I'll read the documentation all the way through. I just tried it and that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not glitched text, perhaps it is text overwriting because you are creating text on top of one another(As JacksonPro said) inside the function. So create the label outside the function and update it using `config` on the inside, like:

```
label = Label(root)
def update(txt):
    label.config(text=txt)
    label.grid(row=1,columnspan=2,padx=5,pady=5)
```

Now you can also remove `global`, as variables defined outside functions are available to the global scope. Also keep a note to increase indentation to customary 4 spaces, even 2 or 1 or even 10 is fine, but it is better to stick with conventions.

Comment: This works, thank you. I'll keep that in mind.